# Auto import dependecies from my library

Tags: android, dependencies, android-library

I created an android library that acts as a wrapper. I use some dependencies in the library notably `Volley` and `Google Play Services`. When I try to paste the .aar file in the project and compile it these libraries are not being imported and they throw an error. When I manually add these dependencies in the `build.gradle` of the new project then they work fine.

Is there way so that whenever my library is added it will auto import all the required dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

just a friendly warning: including dependencies is considered a very bad practice at SHOULD BE AVOIDED.

However, if you do still want to do that, I suggest using the "download library from Maven" feature in Android Studio as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/downloading-libraries-from-maven-repositories.html).

This will make sure the library and all of its dependencies are downloaded.

Comment: Are you saying I should have dependencies in my libraries? I am writing a wrapper class for a Google Play Services API. Without the Play Services dependency my app won't even work. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: If you really need that dependency in your library (I get it it's a wrapper), you should use `provided ` instead of `compile`. Have a look here (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html) under Library dependency configurations

Comment: I tried the `provided` keyword but I am getting the same error. It is not downloading the dependencies.